# React -Server-side-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ssr

I am using react 16.2.0 and doing SSR. 
My web app blink after hydration. 
So to find error or mismatch in server rendered HTML and client rendered HTML, I ran the code in development mode. 
Now it shows

```
warning.js?6db0:33 Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>.
```

I know this error is due to deletion of some div from server rendered HTML to client rendered HTML.

But now, my question is ...how to debug this? there is no reference to element node where it is happening. 
One solution is to check the whole page manually.
Is there any other way..more efficient. 
How to resolve this warning?

Comment: You can try to check the whole page semi-manually with diff tool. E.g. open meld (multiplatform diff-tool), create new diff and copy rendered and fetched html.

Comment: i will try.. is there any other way

Comment: Are you using react router in your application? I came across the same issue, as my SSR render is wrapped in a div (the div your rendered react is injected into), however my client side was not wrapped in a div as the react router code does not require it (it is the app wrapper). If this resolves your issue I will post this up as an answer.

Comment: @JackDalton no it doen't have extra div ... but we have an extra attribute `<div data-reactroot="">` is this the reason ?

Comment: This is what I was referring to. So yes, I believe this is the issue. Unfortunately I am unsure as to how you fix this. I would suggest appending a div to mirror this additional data-react-root div, and see if that works.

Comment: @JackDalton I corrected that.. but still same error..I eliminated all diff... no luck

Comment: When bundle.js is executed, it's going to delete the content inside the root div and recreate it in JS. I believe this is the reason for the blink.

Comment: Is getting rid of the warning your main concern now, or is it eliminating the blink ?